# Sorting a string and int in a 2d array

Tags: java

I have a 2d array

```
String[][] Red= {
        {" B"," A","C","E","F","D","J"},
        {"5", " 3","9","10","1","2","4"}
                     };
```

And I want to sort the numbers in the array.I can manage to sort the letters but not the numbers any help?
here is my current code

```
public static void ArrayCreator() {

        String[][] Red = {
            {" B", " A", "C", "E", "F", "D", "J"},
            {"5", " 3", "9", "10", "1", "2", "4"}
        };  
        DayTwoAssingment.ArraySorter(Red);
    }

    public static void ArraySorter(String[][] Green) {
        String[][] Blue = Green;
        for (int i = 0; i < Blue.length; i++) {
            Arrays.sort(Blue[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Blue));
    }
```

Comment: How do you sort the letters?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Red.length; i++) {
  Arrays.sort(Red[i]);
  }

Comment: You need to provide us with some sort of an 'attempt'. A single 2D array isn't really showing much effort lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you expect the "numbers" in the array to be sorted as integers when, in reality, they are strings. If you do this:

```
String[] numbers = {"5", " 3","9","10","1","2","4"};
Arrays.sort(numbers);
for (String s : numbers) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You get:

```
 3
1
10
2
4
5
9
```

Which is correct, since you are sorting strings.

If you want to sort them as integers, you can create two arrays, instead of one:

```
String[] letters = {" B"," A","C","E","F","D","J"};
Integer[] numbers = {5, 3, 9, 10, 1, 2, 4};
```

Sorting these should get you the result you want.

On the other hand, if you absolutely need to keep both integers and strings in the same array, you can do:

```
Object[][] red = {{" B"," A","C","E","F","D","J"},
                  {5, 3, 9, 10, 1, 2, 4}};
```

This way, when you sort using your loop, you will get the elements of the second array sorted as integers. This solves the problem, though I don't think it is good practice to use an `Object` array and mix types like this.

Comment: I would use this method but my teacher assignment is to use a 2d array with integers and strings and sort and right now I can only get the strings

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `Comparator`. Also, the space before the `3` causes issues, so I trimmed it off:

```
String[][] Red = { { " B", " A", "C", "E", "F", "D", "J" },
                   { "5", " 3", "9", "10", "1", "2", "4" } };

for (int i = 0; i < Red.length; i++) {
    Arrays.sort(Red[i], new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(s1.trim()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2.trim()));
            }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }                   
        }
    });
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Red));
```

The output is:

> [[ A,  B, C, D, E, F, J], [1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 9, 10]]